# Xampp Virtual Hosts redirecting to localhost instead of the right folder

Tags: apache, xampp

I try to use a Virtual Hosts on xampp (apache 2.4), on Windows 10.
I've been through a lot of topics and posts and tried every combination of port etc, and I couldn't make it work.
When I try to access my project it redirects me to localhost (default).

Here's my system32/drivers/etc/hosts :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   yanns-properties.test
```

Here's my httpd-vhosts.conf :

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

# Site: yanns-properties
<VirtualHost *:8080> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/yanns-properties" 
    ServerName yanns-properties.test 
    CustomLog "C:/xampp/htdocs/yanns-properties/custom.log" combined 
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/yanns-properties"> 
       Options All 
       AllowOverride All 
       Require all granted 
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

I also put in my httpd.conf file :

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080
```

When I try to access yanns-properties.test, it redirects me to localhost (with list of file since I renamed index).
I tested with various port, with my project in a different folder ... I don't know what to do anymore.

Thanks for your help !

I